# Javascript error when moving recurring appointments

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, telerik, radscheduler

Using the RadSchedular, a RadWindow appears when moving an appointment in a series of recurring appointments asking me if I want to move them al or just the current appointment.

No matter what I choose an error is thrown telling me that object 'this' does not contain a method called 'get_owner'.
The Telerik.Web.UI dll's are on version 2014.2.724.40 and the project is an ASP.NET project.

The error occurs in a dynamic blank script and looks like this:

```
_onAppointmentMoveCallback:function(j,h){h.Scheduler._raiseRecurrenceActionDialogClosedEvent(h,false,b.RecurrenceAction.Move);
var k={appointment:h.Appointment,newStartTime:h.NewStart,editingRecurringSeries:j,targetSlot:h.TargetSlot,isAbortedByUser:false};
var i=a.raiseCancellableControlEvent(h.Scheduler,"appointmentMoveEnd",k);
//Error in next if()
if((this.get_owner().get_groupBy()!==g)&&this.get_owner()._webServiceSettings.get_isEmpty()&&h.Appointment.get_resources().indexOf(h.SourceSlot.get_resource())==-1){i=true;
}if(!i){h.Scheduler.moveAppointment(h.Appointment,j,h.SourceSlot,h.TargetSlot);
}else{h.Appointment._abortDrag();
}}
```

If I understand correctly, this is Telerik's internal code and I can't do anything about it? Is there anyone who encountered the same problem?

These two images reflect on the debugger state:

[image: Error location]
[image: Watch]

Comment: I imagine this question would be better off targeted at [Telerik's support team](http://www.telerik.com/support).

Comment: I figured, but I don't own official support and their forum is extremely slow.
Since there's always at least on active savvy on this forum, I posted my question here too.

Comment: I suppose this is the forum thread where a solution may surface (i.e., your thread) http://www.telerik.com/forums/error-when-moving-recurring-appointment
I also have no idea what may be the problem. An idea is to try cancelling the AppointmentMoveEnd event to see if this helps even with some loss of functionality: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/scheduler-onclientappointmentmoveend.html or consider updating the data source manually after that with the data from the event.